# How to set a DataTable to a DataGridView so that the data in the DataTable will show int he DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to have a grid view on my form that when I click a button it will load some test data into the DataGridView.

The name is called grid in the properties. For some reason my DataTable is not being loaded into the DataGridView and thus will not show on my form.

Code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

        DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
        grid.DataSource = table;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You are creating a *new* DataGridView control.  Are you adding it to the form?  Otherwise, just update the grid that is currently on the form.

Comment: add `grid.DataBind();` after `grid.DataSource = table;` line.

Comment: @Iqbal It isn't tagged, but the image is clearly a WinForm.  No BindDate() call there.

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: Dear please don't create the `DataGridView` at runtime if you have already created using form designer, just use the same, check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** You are not adding the `DataGridView` Control on the Form which was created at the runtime

**Solution :** You need to add the `DataGridView` to the Form

Add these 2 statements :

```
    grid1.Location = new Point(100,100);//x and y axis
    this.Controls.Add(grid1);
```

OR

if you create  `DataGridView` in Form Designer you can use the same `DataGridView` without creating the new one in runtime to bind the data as below:

Replace This:

```
grid.DataSource = table;
```

With This:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

**EDIT:**  changing width of columns from Designer

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It work. Is there a way in C# DataGridView to be able to drag open the columns more so or do you have to to that programmatically.

Comment: you can just create the columns at design time and assign width property of each column or you can change it from runtime. see my edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

try this

i assume that grid already in your form not add run time

```
table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

and if you add gridcontrol on button click event then

```
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

    DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
    grid.Location = new Point(50, 50);
    this.Controls.Add(grid);
    grid.DataSource = table;
```